# htaccess structure, what goes where

Tags: .htaccess

I'm just wondering if I've got my htaccess structure correct, I cant find much info about the *where* to place things in the htaccess file, So I just kinda threw it all together.  But without wanting to paste the entire htaccess in here, a summary of my htaccess is as as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

order allow,deny
deny from {IP}
allow from all

#Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

ErrorDocument 403 /foo/bar/403.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>        
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

</IfModule>


# Redirects
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)^/some-fancy-url/?$ /foo/bar/page.php
```

There's a lot more `RedirectMatch`s in there, and `RewriteCond`.  It all seems to be working fine.  Two questions I have:

1. Does anything else in there need to be moved inside the `<ifmodule>` block?
2. Should the `RedirectMatche`s be at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your use case. The .htaccess file is processed in the order you write the lines.

Example:

If your conditions inside the `<IfModule>` matches a request, the `RedirectMatch` is never reached, since the `RewriteRule` is marked as `[L]`, meaning `Last`.
If you want to have the `RedirectMatch rule to have a higher priority you have to move it up. If the priority is fine right now, leave it as it is.

Regarding the `move inside the IfModule block`:

The `<IfModule>` directive checkes if the given module is loaded.

Upside: If the module is not loaded for some reason, Apache will still start without producing an error.
Downside: Your application might not work because the rewrite is not working.

You can just remove the `<IfModule>` directives, so you detect the problem with the missing module immediately at Apache startup. Of course in that case nothing will work, because Apache won't start.

It's up to you how you want the server to behave.

Moving the `AddOutputFilterByType` (or other) directives inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` doesn't make any sense, because they are not dependent on that module.
It would make more sense to surround them with their own module, `mod_deflate`:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
# ... and so on
</IfModule>
```

The only thing I'd change on your file is to omit the first `RewriteEngine On` line. It is only necessary once, and you already have it correctly inside your `<IfModule>` block.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps.  I'm thinking then maybe to move the `RedirectMatch`s to above the `mod_rewrite` block.  Does it also make sense to surround them with `mod_alias`?

Comment: "If your conditions inside the `<IfModule>` matches a request, the `RedirectMatch` is never reached" - Actually, yes they will. `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive, so it will still get processed (on the original request) after mod_rewrite has executed - regardless of the apparent order of the directives. (Another reason for not mixing the two modules; confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

The order of your directives look OK. However, it's generally not a good idea to mix mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) and mod_alias (`RedirectMatch`) directives in the same context. Explanation below...

With Apache config files, the different Apache modules (mod_rewrite, mod_alias, mod_expires, mod_access_compat/mod_authz_host, etc.) are processed independently, regardless of the apparent order of the directives in the config file. But within each module, the directives are generally processed top-down (as you would expect).

If the directives were all processed top-down, then your `RedirectMatch` directives at the end might never get processed, because the mod_rewrite "front controller" that precedes it rewrites all requests for non-existent files to `index.php`. So, the mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directives at the end are only *reliably* processed because the modules execute independently. However, mod_rewrite does execute before mod_alias anyway, so the request is possibly being rewritten to `index.php` before the redirect occurs (`RedirectMatch` works on the original request URL, so you are OK here).

> 2. Should the `RedirectMatch`es be at the top?

It would be more logical to have the external redirects before the internal rewrites (your mod_rewrite front controller). However, since you are using mod_alias for your redirects, they execute anyway.

However, as mentioned in my opening paragraph, "it's generally not a good idea to mix mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) and mod_alias (`RedirectMatch`) directives in the same context." - This is because you can get unexpected conflicts. It depends on exactly what you are doing, but if you have both `RewriteRule` and `RedirectMatch` directives that both match the requested URL then it's not necessarily obvious which will execute (which is *independent* of the order of the directives). For this reason, it would be preferable to convert the mod_alias `RedirectMatch` to mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directives. If you do this then the `RewriteRule` directives obviously must then go *before* the existing mod_rewrite font-controller, otherwise they may never execute.

> Does anything else in there need to be moved inside the `<ifmodule>` block?

You don't actually need the `<IfModule>` block at all here. This is only required if your application is designed to work without mod_rewrite. And I doubt this is the case. eg. WordPress uses an `<IfModule>` wrapper because it can work OK without mod_rewrite (you just don't get so nice "pretty" URLs). If you use an `<IfModule>` wrapper and mod_rewrite is not installed then this just fails silently. Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper and you get a fatal error - which occurs before the system goes live and you can easily fix it!

However, a valid reason to use `<IfModule>` blocks is if you have one module that is dependent on another being enabled. eg. You wanted to set a `Header` (with mod_headers) on the condition that the URL was rewritten using mod_rewrite. In this case you could include the `Header` directive inside an `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper. However, these cases are fairly rare.

---

Regarding the multiple `RewriteEngine` directives. As Gerald has already stated, you only need one. It is more logical to have this at the top of your file (or once with the block of mod_rewrite directives - if they are in a concise block further down the file).

However, this is an example of where the top-down execution (within a module) kind of breaks down (which is why I stated only "*generally* processed top-down" above). You can place the `RewriteEngine On` directive *anywhere* in the config file and it still works - you can place it at the very end if you wanted to (but that is confusing)! If you have multiple `RewriteEngine` directives then the last one in the file wins and controls the *entire file* (when I say "file", strictly speaking I mean "context"). You can't turn mod_rewrite On/Off throughout the file. It's either On or Off for the entire file. This also means that you can quickly disable *all* mod_rewrite directives by simply placing a single `RewriteEngine Off` directive on the very last line of the file - you don't need to comment out the directives. (The same thing applies to the `RewriteBase` directive.)